# Why there is a space between border and content?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, border, space

I encountered a problem while creating a card in react (using tailwind for CSS). Here, I have given border and border radius to the parent div. The parent div contains one child div and a paragraph.
I wonder why there is a space between border and div with the heading "COMPASSION". You may not see it at first sight but there is a tiny space, please see it carefully.

```js
import React from "react";

const OurValue = ({ img, title, desc }) => {
  return (
    <div className="w-full md:w-[47%] border-2 border-primary rounded-md">
      <div className="py-4 flex items-center bg-primary rounded-t-md">
        <i className="px-4">
          <img src={img} alt="icons" />
        </i>
        <h1 className="text-xl font-semibold text-white uppercase">{title}</h1>
      </div>
      <p className="py-4 px-4 text-sm text-gray-600">{desc}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default OurValue;
```

[Here is what troubled me]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhIh4.png

Comment: Refer this link on how to ask/create a proper question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  For purely CSS styling issues, please create a runnable [mcve] to demonstrate the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.